# Show function in Jquery not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use some show hide functions in my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#me').hide();
    $('#send').click(function() {
        $('#me').show("slow");
    });
});
```

for some reason, when i click the id="send" button, the id="me"(a picture)

is not showing up again(though it disappears):

```
<div id="me">
    <img src="Me.JPG" alt="me" width="450" height="450" alt="picture" align="right"/>
</div>
```

help please?

please let me know if i have to add more code to make myself clear...

thank you!

EDIT:

here is the code for the send button:

```
<input type="submit" id="send" value=" Send " class="submit" />
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the send button.

Comment: Must be something more to it..  Working fine for me, I just made a `<button>` tag called send.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zs7W2/

Comment: just added the submit button code...

Comment: Does the image actually display when you comment the hide() function?

Comment: Oh.. Probably it's running the script, and then submitting the form.  I've updated my answer with a couple solutions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the most likely answer is the `send` button does not yet exist when your page is loaded.  Is this button being created dynamically, or through some other mechanism?  To debug, I would say:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#me').hide();
     alert(document.getElementById('send')); //Test if it exists
     $('#send').click(function() {
      $('#me').show("slow");
    });
   });
```

If you get a popup with `null`, then you'll have to track down where this button gets generated and bind the event there.

Other than that, as you can tell from:

[jsfiddle.net/zs7W2/](http://jsfiddle.net/zs7W2/)

Your code works fine.

**UPDATE:**

I believe your `FORM` is actually submitting itself.  You should change your code to:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#me').hide();
     $('#send').click(function() {
      $('#me').show("slow");
      return false; //Prevent submit
    });
   });
```

Or, use a `<button type="button">` or `<input type="button">`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zs7W2/7/

Comment: well, i opened the html again, and i saw that the image is being loaded and after a milisec it disappears again... have no idea why this is happening

Comment: Yea, sounds like your form is being submitted and thus the whole page is reloaded again.  Can you change `<input type="submit" id="send" class="submit" />` to `<input type="button" id="send" class="submit" />` and try?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="me">
 <img src="Me.jpg" alt="me" width="450" height="450" alt="picture" align="right"/>
 </div>
<input type="button" id="send" value="Submit">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#me').hide();
     $('#send').click(function() {
      $('#me').show("slow");
    });
   });

</script>
```

I've used something like this. It works. I guess that some problem with image align. Try to change it.